# How do I see who created the tag in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have found too many tags in gerrit repo but didn't know who create them.I have tried clone repo to my workspace and used "git show TAG".It doesn't work.[image]

If the tag tag person adds the -a option then I can see who created the tag. How do I see who created the tag without adding the -a option

Comment: Check the access rights of the project to find out who have the permission `Create Reference` under the reference pattern `refs/tags/*` or `refs/*`. The pattern could be a regex like `^refs/tags/.+$`. If you have access to the gerrit server, you could also find clues from ssh logs or http logs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer，I know who has all these permissions but I'd like to see the person who created the tag on the Web page

Comment: Without annotations (`git tag -a`), *Git* does not store this information anywhere. Whether *Gerrit* stores it anywhere, and if so where and/or for how long, I have no idea.

Comment: You say "I'd like to see the person who created..." Is it possible that its not human at all but some process, like a CI tool or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know who created a lightweight (non-annotated) tag, neither using Git nor using Gerrit.

If this is an issue to you, consider denying the access rights to create lightweight tags.

Comment: There *might* be a way if the push logs on a/the server go far enough back and details who pushed a tag for the first time. Assuming the tag was created locally that is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a (reasonable) way.

Comment: how could I deny the access rights to create lightweight tags

Comment: I have got it.without open permission "Create Reference" on "refs/tags/*"